# Metric space. Open Ball

Tags: metric-spaces

Is $(\mathbf{N}, d)$ metric space if:

$d(m,n)=\begin{cases}
0& m=n\\
\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}& m\neq n
\end{cases}$.  $m, n \in  \mathbf{N}$

(Note: it's easily proven that it is.)

If it is, does it genearate discrete topology? What sets do the open balls $B(5,1), B(2,2), B(3,\frac{1}{3})$ represent in that space?

Answer (score 2):

I presume that you are working in $\mathbb{N}=\left\{ 1,2,3,\dots\right\} $

Singleton $\left\{ n\right\} =\left\{ m\mid d\left(n,m\right)<\frac{1}{n}\right\} $
is open, implying that the topology is discrete.

$B\left(5,1\right)=\left\{ m\mid d\left(5,m\right)<1\right\} =\left\{ 5\right\} \cup\left\{ m\mid\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{m}<1\right\} $

So just solve the inequality $\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{m}<1$

The others can be done likewise.

Answer (score 1):

This space has a nice geometric picture: you can view it as the set of all points $1/n$ for positive integers $n$, with the metric defined as the distance that you must travel between two points *going via the origin*.

Now the discrete topology means that every singleton set is open, so every singleton must be contained in a ball of some radius. Given this picture, it is straightforward to come up with such a ball for any given $n$: it has radius $1/n$ (or less). So the topology is indeed discrete.

As for the balls you give, the picture makes it clear that $B(5,1)$ contains everything except 1, $B(2,2)$ is the whole space, and $B(3,1/3)$ is the singleton $\{3\}$.

A more interesting space can be obtained by adding the origin itself to the set. It's a good exercise to work out what the open sets look like in this case.